# How to ignore a specific file for redirection in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

My server provides the default redirection from www.test.com to test.com
I want to remove the redirection for one specific file 'abc.php' there. How to go about it?

The default redirection provided in the .htaccess file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this (for abc.php):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*/)?abc\.php$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: ahhh darnit you were a few secs earlier than me

Comment: @Jonan life is short, don't sleep :D